# Assigned variable to function(each statement in jQuery) not having values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use this jQuery dropdown filter plugin from GitHub https://github.com/rbayliss/Dropdown-Table-Filter. In my case, the table format is like this:

```
<table id="table_2">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Items </th>
      <th> Quantity </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td> Apple </td>
     <td> 20 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td> Orange </td>
     <td> 20 </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So, re-modelling the plugin to suit this case was necessary:

```
var table = $(this);
    $('thead tr th:visible', table).each(function(index) {
         var selectbox = $('<select>');
         var values = [];
         var opts = new Array();
         selectbox.append('<option value="--all--">' + $(this).text() + '</option>');
     for(var noOfTr = 0; noOfTr<2; noOfTr++) {
          var tr = $('tbody tr:eq('+ noOfTr +')',table);
          var col = tr.find('td:eq(' + (index) + ')').each(function(index) {
            var cellVal = escape($.trim($(this).text()));
            if(cellVal.length == 0) {
            cellVal = '--empty--';
          }
          $(this).attr('ddtf-value', cellVal);

          if($.inArray(cellVal, values) === -1) {
            var cellText = $.trim($(this).text());
            if(cellText.length == 0) {cellText = '--Empty--';}
            values.push(cellVal);
            opts.push({val:cellVal, text:cellText});
          }
        });
    }       
}
```

The variable assigned to the function "col" is not containing any value after the execution whereas the "opts" is getting populated correctly. Please help me out in populating col.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
var col = tr.find('td:eq(' + (noOfTr) + ')').each(function(index) {
```

instead of:

```
var col = tr.find('td:eq(' + (index) + ')').each(function(index) {
```

since the auto increment variable is `noOfTr` not `index`.

Comment: I have edited the code now so that it makes clear of what is "index" and "$(this)" means.